# How do I send simple mails from a gem, without requiring ActionMailer, but using its configuration if present?

Tags: ruby, email, configuration, rubygems, actionmailer

I have a gem that will under certain circumstances, send very simple e-mail with information. They have a very simple, hard-coded body and subject.

Because of this, I'm requiring Mail and using it directly, rather than ActionMailer. That way, I can have users of my gem that don't use ActionMailer, and I don't have to create the Mailer itself in my gem, which is overkill.

My question is around configuration of mail/actionmailer.

For users of my gem that will be using Mail directly, they will be setting the config, and my gem will magically be able to send mails and all is good. However, I do expect most people to be using ActionMailer in their projects, they will have ActionMailer configuration in their environment initializers, and I'd like my gem to use that, instead of forcing my user to configure their e-mail settings twice.

I've been looking at the code of Mail and ActionMailer, and I haven't been able to figure out how the ActionMailer configuration that is set in the initializers ends up trickling down to Mail. It clearly does, somehow, but I haven't found out how.

What is the best way to do this?

Are there any gems that allow you to use either Mail or ActionMailer, and will just work with the configuration you already added for those?

---

I'm not sure my description is clear enough... To clarify what I want:

In the initializers of a typical user of my gem, there will be something like this for ActionMailer users:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: "username",
    password: "password",
    domain: "blah.com",
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 587,
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Or this for Mail users:

```
Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, { 
        :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port                 => 587,
        :domain               => 'your.host.name',
        :user_name            => '<username>',
        :password             => '<password>',
        :authentication       => 'plain',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

end
```

I want the configuration of my gem to be this:

```
MyGem.configure do |config|
    config.email_target = "blah@blah.com"
end
```

And when my gem needs to send an e-mail:

```
  mail = Mail.new do
    from     MyGem.configuration.email_target
    to       MyGem.configuration.email_target
    subject  'Notification: #{something}'
    body     message_body
  end
  mail.deliver!
```

Now, in the second configuration scenario (Mail.defaults), this will work.
In the first one (config.action_mailer), it won't.

Can I make this work without demanding extra config work from the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically, wrap_delivery_behavior is what copies the ActionMailer configuration into Mail, so calling wrap_delivery_behavior if ActionMailer is defined solves the problem:

```
  mail = Mail.new do
    from     recipient
    to       recipient
    subject  subject
    body     body
  end

  if defined?(ActionMailer)
    ActionMailer::Base.wrap_delivery_behavior(mail)
  end

  mail.deliver!
```

That works exactly as I needed it to